# Convertir campo Blob de fichero OSM .mbtiles leido desde qt en una BD SQLite a QPixmap

Tags: qt

estoy intentando leer desde una bd SQLite el campo BLOB de un fichero .mbtiles, con la finalidad de representar ese dato como imagen, pero en la conversión de este campo a QPixmap me resulta inválido el pixmap, uso Qt 5.7.

En el gestor SQLite, el BLOB está en formato obf pero cuando intento convertirlo a QPixmap no hace la conversión correctamente.

Comment: Qt no soporta mbtiles de forma nativa, una posible solucion es que instales este plugin https://github.com/tumic0/QtPBFImagePlugin que añade esa funcionalidad

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda de antemano, desde Qt he logrado leer un mbtiles, no directamente, sino a través de consultas SQL. Ahora, descargue un fichero mbtiles desde openmaptiles.com pero este si no me deja obtener la imagen del campo BLOB. Estare mirando el plugin que me recomiendas. Cuando tenga algo , comento., igual si tienes algo más y puedes ayudarme pues súper agradecido......

Comment: Podrias mostrar como estas intentando leer.